# migrate (UI): URL alias problem

Tags: 7, migrations

I'm doing some migration tests since we need to migrate content from Drupal 7 site A to Drupal 7 site B. The only issue I have is the path auto alias, for some reason it just won't migrate. I always seem to get a domain.tld/node/2122.

I already tried checking off the 'DNMG' checkbox and the other one with a path, none of them seem to help.

Can somebody point me in the right direction.

Facts:

- Path alias migrates, eg: site.tld/content/hell-world
- Path alias and node redirects are in the database:  node/123 goes to site.tld/content/hello-world in the redirect screen
- In reality 'node/123' does **not** redirect to the alias, even though it should be.
- tried it with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto), path, [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) modules disabled, same problem
- tried bulk updating alias, same problem.

I really don't know where to look anymore, I'm all doing this via the UI, since it works just fine except the url alias problem.

PS: if you post a code snippet, I need to know where to put it...

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please check the url_alias table in your database and tell us if the value in the 'language' column matches the language of your site.